# HTML/CSS Align (inline, horizontally) & Keep Right

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to get these icons to sit next to each other in the header with aligned in the middle (vertically), and kept on the right side of the page (maybe a float?)

http://jsfiddle.net/qNWeV/1/

Here is an image of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: What I'm trying to accomplish]

```
<!-- HEADER -->
    <div class="header">
        <img class="center-header" src="images/center_header.png" />

        <!-- BUTTONS (header) -->
        <div class="header-buttons-right">
            <!-- Notification Icon -->
            <div class="notify-div" class="right-margin"> <span id="notify-span"> 1 </span> </div>
            <div class="gear-settings"> <!-- Gear Settings --> </div>
            <div class="menu-button"> <!-- Menu Button --> </div>
        </div>

    </div>


/* ******************* */
/*        TOP-NAV      */
/* ******************* */
.header {
    background-color:rgb(243,243,243);
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    border-color:rgb(243,243,243);
    border-width:2px;
    /* Firefox v1.0+ */
    -moz-border-radius:0%;
    /* Safari v3.0+ and by Chrome v0.2+ */
    -webkit-border-radius:0%/3%;
    /* Firefox v4.0+ , Safari v5.0+ , Chrome v4.0+ , Opera v10.5+  and by IE v9.0+ */
    border-radius:0%/3%;
    border-style:solid;
}
.center-header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1002;
    left: 50%;
    top: -45px;
    margin-left: -135px;
}
.header-buttons-right {
    float: right;
}
.notify-div {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url('../images/notify-round.png') no-repeat center;
    text-align: center;
}
    #notify-span {
        position: relative;
        top: 3px;
        font-family:"Futura LT Bold";
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:117%;
        color:rgb(255,255,255);
    }
.gear-settings {
    background: url('../images/gear-settings.png') no-repeat center;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu-button {
    background: url('../images/menu.png') no-repeat center;
    width: 24px;
    height: 21px;
}
```

Comment: you could float:right the notify-div

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="header"> 
    <img class="center-header" src="images/center_header.png" /> 
                <!-- BUTTONS (header) -->
    <div class="header-buttons-right"> 
        <!-- Notification Icon -->
        <span class="notify-div right-margin">
            <span id="notify-span"> 1 </span> 
        </span>
        <span class="gear-settings"> G</span>
        <span class="menu-button">M</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
/* ******************* */
/*        TOP-NAV      */
/* ******************* */

.header {
    background-color: rgb(243,243,243);
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border:2px solid rgb(243,243,243);
/* Firefox v1.0+ */
-moz-border-radius:0%;
/* Safari v3.0+ and by Chrome v0.2+ */
-webkit-border-radius:0%/3%;
/* Firefox v4.0+ , Safari v5.0+ , Chrome v4.0+ , Opera v10.5+  and by IE v9.0+ */
border-radius:0%/3%;
}
.center-header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1002;
    left: 50%;
}
.header-buttons-right {
    float: right;
    width:200px;
}
.notify-div {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url('../images/notify-round.png') no-repeat center;
    text-align: center;

}
#notify-span {
    font-family: "Futura LT Bold";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
.gear-settings {
    background: url('../images/gear-settings.png') no-repeat center;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
.menu-button {
    background: url('../images/menu.png') no-repeat center;
    width: 24px;
    height: 21px;
}
```

**Jsfiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/VJGUM/

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the height of the header I would suggest giving the container for your icons the same height and line-height.

You can then float this container right and, if the icons are inline-blocks, you can set their `vertical-align: middle;`

Here I've removed the icon images and given the divs background colors instead to better illustrate the outcome:

http://jsfiddle.net/qNWeV/1/

If you'll notice I've removed the spaces in between the closing div tag of each icon and the opening div tag.  Because they are set as inline-block, the browser will add a space, and I would much rather control this with a margin.